# How to display different layers in each 3D View?

Tags: interface, workflow, layers

How can I show different layers in separate windows? For example, show layer 1 and 2 in one window, and show layer 3 and 4 in another window?

I need this so I can see everything I am doing correctly since I do have a messy rig.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Disable *lock layers to scene* in *3D view > Header* to use local layers:

[image]

Then each 3D view can have it's own visible layers.

Comment: Wow! This is a very useful trick. I wish I knew it earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you heaps :) Seems like i asked a great question :P