# Can you view 2 or more layers simultaneously?

Tags: render-layers

Is it possible in Blender to view 2 or more layers at once?

Thank You

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/how-to-display-different-layers-in-each-3d-view

Answer (score 5):

Yes, to see more than one layer at a time shift-click on the other layers you want to view. It will make them visible without closing the others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you hold shift and then click on the layers you want to be viewing they should highlight and you should see all the layers visible in the viewport.