# blender viewport unlink

Tags: 3d-view

In the 3D view header, we can see a small button that looks like a link chain: 
[image]
What does this button actually do? Please give me a demonstration.

Comment: It is a switch that allows you to show different layers in separate windows. Read: [How to display different layers in each 3D View?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/how-to-display-different-layers-in-each-3d-view/19245#19245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is a switch that allows you to show different layers in separate windows. If toggled all views show the same layers.

[image]

Read: [How to display different layers in each 3D View?]

([How to display different layers in each 3D View?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/how-to-display-different-layers-in-each-3d-view/19245#19245))

Comment: I think it'd be very useful if one view could be in edit mode and other viewport in object mode.... however this doesn't seem to be available as a feature, do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: @mathmaniage please ask new quesions using the Ask Question link at the top.